# Stop HttpWebRequest from checking my payload

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, json-rpc

I need to send custom payloads to a webserver and I use HttpWebRequest for doing this. In my case, it is a json-rpc. I thing it does not matter what I send, as long as it isnt form-data encoded like in html forms or the attachments of mails.

See my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.108/api/homematic.cgi");

byte[] rpc_request = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{ \"method\": \"Session.login\", \"params\": [ \"username\": \"root\", \"password\": \"root\" ], \"id\": null}");

request.ContentLength = rpc_request.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/json";

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    stream.Write(rpc_request, 0, rpc_request.Length);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Console.WriteLine("Status Code = {0}", response.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

Very simple. But C# does not like the content of the payload and throws a `System.Net.ProtocolViolationException` when calling `request.GetRequestStream().Write`. I cant even start the request!

Why does C# look at the content of the payload at all and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write to the request stream make sure that you are using some verb different than a `GET`. A `POST` could be a good candidate for sending data to a web server.

```
request.Method = "POST";
```

If you don't explicitly specify the HTTP verb, then `GET` is assumed which explains why you are getting an error.

Also you might consider wrapping `IDisposable` resources in `using` statements just to make your code a lil'bit better. Not to mention the unused `webClient` variable that might be worth getting rid of:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.108/api/homematic.cgi");
string requestBody = "{ \"method\": \"Session.login\", \"params\": [ \"username\": \"root\", \"password\": \"root\" ], \"id\": null}";

request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    stream.Write(requestBody);
}

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Status Code = {0}", response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This seems to work, but why does C# do it differently when the method changes? The payload part is in every method the same, or is it?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure that I understand your question. It's how the HTTP protocol works. If you want to send a body along with the request you use POST or PUT verbs. A GET verb doesn't have a body. So it's not really a problem with C#. The framework is just telling you that you are violating the protocol that you are using by attempting to write to the request stream when making a GET verb. For further reference, I would recommend you reading the HTTP protocol specification: http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2616.txt